# Bigquery Api Java client intermittently returning bad results

Tags: google-bigquery, google-client

I am executing some long running quires using the big-query java client.

I construct a big-query job and execute like this

```
val queryRequest = new QueryRequest().setQuery(query)
val queryJob = client.jobs().query(ProjectId, queryRequest)
queryJob.execute()
```

The problem I am facing is the for the same query, the client returns before the job is complete i.e. the number of rows in result is zero.

I tried printing the response and it shows

```
{"jobComplete":false,"jobReference":{"jobId":"job_bTLRGrw5_xR26i9Li3a9EQvuA6c","projectId":"analytics-production"},"kind":"bigquery#queryResponse"}
```

From that I can see that the job is not complete. The why did the client return before the job is complete ?

While building the client, I use the `HttpRequestInitializer` and in the initialize method I provide the timeout parameters.

```
override def initialize(request: HttpRequest): Unit = {
  request.setConnectTimeout(...)
  request.setReadTimeout(...)
}
```

Tried giving high values for timeout like 240 seconds etc..but no luck. The behavior is still the same. It fails intermitently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the timeout on the Bigquery request body, and not the HTTP object.

```
val queryRequest = new QueryRequest().setQuery(query).setTimeoutMs(10000) //10 seconds
```

The param is `timeoutMs`. This is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query

Please also read the docs regarding this field: How long to wait for the query to complete, in milliseconds, before the request times out and returns. Note that this is only a timeout for the request, not the query. **If the query takes longer to run than the timeout value, the call returns without any results and with the 'jobComplete' flag set to false.** You can call GetQueryResults() to wait for the query to complete and read the results. The default value is 10000 milliseconds (10 seconds).

More about Synchronous queries here
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#syncqueries

Comment: How's the request.setReadTimeout() and setQuery().setTimeoutMs() related ?

Comment: `setReadTimeout` is for the connection itself while it's being kept open. `setQuery timeout` is for the query itself.